# Typescript, how to redeclare complex library types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is components library, that uses TS. After build I get next typings folder with next structure:

```
typings
-- core
---- ThemeVariants.d.ts // exports type Variants
-- components
---- Button.d.ts // import Variants type from core/ThemeVariants, export ButtonProps = {variant?: Variants['button']}
-- index.d.ts // exports all from core and components
```

When I use my components library in product, I need to redeclare `Variants` type, in order to change ButtonProps. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *"When I use my components library in product, I need to redeclare Variants type, in order to change ButtonProps."* Why? And in what way? The library presumably defines its types according to what its code expects. If you change them, you may well be giving the library incorrect data to work with, causing unexpected results.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you pls provide an example

Comment: My library have two different theme providers for two different products. In first product Button have `variant` prop, that can be 'success' | 'danger', in second product `variant` prop can be 'question' | 'danger'. First product can't use prop value from second product. I need opportunity to rule types from product directly